# Excel counting occurancens of specific order inside column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following column in a Excel spreadsheet:

```
A 
B
Z
A
A
B
C
Z
Z
A
B
A
Z
```

How do I count the orrucence of the order `A B Z` ?

The result of the example should be 3.

```
A -| first occurence
B -|
Z -|
A 
A -| second occurence
B -|
C  |
Z -| 
Z
A -| third occurence
B -| 
A  |
Z -|
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is probably to use a helper column for checking occurrences:

- enter this formula in a new column next to your data:
  `=IF(B1="A",IF(A2="B","B","A"),IF(B1="B",IF(A2="Z",1,"B"),IF(A2="A","A","")))`
- use this formula for counting:
  `=SUM(B:B)`

[image: j]